Upgrading @nestjs/platform-fastify to version 10.4.15 throws error TS2304: Cannot find name 'RawReply'
On upgrading the package to v10.4.15 from v10.1.3, I see the following errors when i try to build the project:
Fn extends preValidationHookHandler<RawServer, RawRequest, RawReply, RouteGeneric, ContextConfig, SchemaCompiler, TypeProvider, Logger> | preValidationAsyncHookHandler<RawServer, RawRequest, RawReply, RouteGeneric, ContextConfig, SchemaCompiler, TypeProvider, Logger> = preValidationHookHandler<RawServer, RawRequest, RawReply, RouteGeneric, ContextConfig, SchemaCompiler, TypeProvider, Logger> 

6.396 node_modules/fastify/types/instance.d.ts:271:311 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'RawRequest'.

Similarly i see errors for Cannot find name 'RawReply', Cannot find name 'RawServer' etc. Any ideas why such errors on a minor patch?
CLI Screenshot for the same: SS

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
